# "Total amount" and "Balance owed" should by default be attributes to the same "contribution"

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm

Good day,

and thanks for your support.
I think I have a pretty common issue: when registering a contribution which is paid off with several payments it is not easy to find a proper solution to have the same transaction in a report indicating the "total amount" and the "balance owed". So far the best approximation that I could find is the "Bookkeeping Transactions" report in the contributions section however this solution has a limitation: the information is in two rows and it is not possible to net those so to have the outstanding debit for the member/contributor. I have to say that Civicrm is really a fantastic product: it is well structured and provides a lot of useful functionalities however when it comes to handling the debit/credit positions of members it makes me wonder why such a simple requirement was never supported. I've tried any type of solution that can be found in the web however none of them satisfies the need. I also tried with [show_balance_due](https://civicrm.org/extensions/show-balance-due) however with the latest version of Civicrm on drupal it does not work. I've also tried [summaryfields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) and [Line Item Report](https://civicrm.org/extensions/line-item-report) but none of these is satisfying the need we have.
I am sure the requirement is known and I think a solution for this would makes sense.

Thanks for reading.

Kind regards
Antonio

ps: we are a small ski team evaluating civicrm to handle our civic organization.

Comment: Welcome to SE!  I'd create an issue on the 'show_balance_due' repo.  Its authors are usually very responsive.

Comment: Thanks Aidan! Kind regards Antonio

Comment: Aidan, sorry for my stupid question: how do I create an issue? Kind regards Antonio

Comment: On the [extension info page](https://civicrm.org/extensions/show-balance-due), click 'Report a bug' just above the 'Download' button.

Comment: As an update for others, this issue was reported and fixed. The latest version of the extension supports CiviCRM 5.38. https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.showbalancedue/issues/3

Comment: @AntonioGuidi if this has fixed your issue, could you add an answer to let others know that this is now working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

apologise for the delay. Yes the issue was solved. It is in plan to have a new official release of the extension, in the meanwhile a patch is available.See [here](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.showbalancedue/pull/1)

Kind regards
Antonio